# Repopulating a SimpleExpandableListAdapter

Tags: android, list, listview, expandablelistview

Whats the best practice when it comes to repopulating the List thats backing up the adapter and then, refreshing & displaying it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit?  What do you mean by refresh exactly, what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When data is changed in an adapater, you have to call `notifyDatasetChaged()`. It should take care of redrawing the list for you.